# When a button is pressed, highlight tab in HTML using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three tabs - **info, question, order** in one part of the webpage. When I click on any of the tab header, only that selected tab highlights. I have two buttons in the info section with link to question and order tab. When the button is pressed, the respective tab is shown correctly, but it does not highlight the respective tab.

This is the URL to the site with the problem, the 3 tabs are located to the right on the page:

https://webb.io/swebrush/produkt/barntandborste/

I did try a Bootstrap code, but it did not work very well either

Help would be much appreciated!

```js
<script>
function openProductTab(evt, tabName) {
    var i, tabcontent, openProductTab;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tabProductLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tabProductLinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tabProductLinks.length; i++) {
        tabProductLinks[i].className = tabProductLinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
</script>
```

```css
/*----------------------*/
/*---Produkttabbar------*/
/*----------------------*/

.tabProdukter {
  overflow: auto;
}

/*----------tab button---------*/


.tabProducts button{
   color:#1e84d8;
   /*margin-bottom: 0 px;*/
    background-color: #e7f6ff;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.1s;
   width:33%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ebebeb;
   border-left: 1px solid #ebebeb;
   border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #20a3eb;
}

.tabProducts button:hover{
  color: white;
   background-color:#20a3eb;
}

.tabProducts button.active {
 color:#1e84d8;
 width: 33%;
 background-color: white;
 border-top: 1px solid #20a3eb;
 border-left: 1px solid #20a3eb;
 border-right: 1px solid #20a3eb;
 border-bottom: none;
}

.tabProducts button.active:hover{
 color: #20a3eb;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
   display: none;
    padding: 0px 0px;
}


.tabcontent ul{
 margin-left:0px;
}

.tabcontent li{
 list-style:none;

}
.tabcontent h3{
 border-bottom:dotted;
 border-bottom-width: 1px;
 border-color: #20a3eb;
 text-align:left;
 padding-top:20px;
 padding-bottom:5px;
 margin-bottom:5px;
  font-size:18px;
}

.tabcontent h4{
  color:#515151;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabProducts" id="ProductInformationTabs">
  <button class="tabProductLinks" onclick="openProductTab(event, 'produktinformation')" id="defaultOpen">[icon name="info-circle" class="" unprefixed_class=""] Info</button><button class="tabProductLinks" onclick="openProductTab(event, 'flerFragor',)">[icon name="question-circle" class="" unprefixed_class=""] Frågor</button><button class="tabProductLinks" onclick="openProductTab(event, 'bestallNu')">[icon name="shopping-cart" class="" unprefixed_class=""] Beställ</button>
</div>

<div id="produktinformation" class="tabcontent">
<ul>
 <li><h3>[icon name="info-circle" class="" unprefixed_class=""]  Produktinformation</h3></li>
 <li>[icon name="clock-o" class="blue1ColorClass" unprefixed_class=""] Leveranstid: <span style="color: #1e84d8;">1-2 veckor</span></li>
 <li>[icon name="arrow-circle-o-down" class="blue1ColorClass" unprefixed_class=""] Minsta antal: <span style="color: #1e84d8;">100 st</span></li>
 <li>[icon name="adjust" class="blue1ColorClass" unprefixed_class=""] Färger: [icon name="circle" class="blueColorClass" unprefixed_class=""] [icon name="circle" class="redColorClass" unprefixed_class=""] [icon name="circle" class="greenColorClass" unprefixed_class=""] [icon name="circle" class="blackColorClass" unprefixed_class=""]</li>
 <li><a href="http://webb.io/swebrush/wp-content/uploads/tandborstar_tryckmall_för_profiltryck.pdf">[icon name="download" class="blue2ColorClass alignright" unprefixed_class=""]</a> Mall för nedladdning: <a href="http://webb.io/swebrush/wp-content/uploads/tandborstar_tryckmall_för_profiltryck.pdf"><span style="color: #1e84d8;">Tandborstar.pdf</a></span></li>

</ul>
<ul>
 <li><h4>Är du intresserad av att beställa produkten?</h4></li>
 <li><button class="buttonDefault" onclick="openProductTab(event, 'flerFragor','defaultOpen')">Jag har fler frågor  [icon name="question-circle" class="" unprefixed_class=""]</button></li>
 <li><button class="buttonOrderClass" onclick="openProductTab(event, 'bestallNu')">Beställ nu  [icon name="shopping-cart" class="" unprefixed_class=""]</button></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="flerFragor" class="tabcontent">
<ul>
 <li><h3>[icon name="question-circle" class="" unprefixed_class=""]  Jag har några frågor först</h3></li>
 <li>Att beställa profilprodukter på webben är inte alltid en dans på rosor. Vilken tur att vi har duktiga personer som gärna assisterar dig i din beställning. Skicka in dina funderingar via kontaktformuläret så återkommer rätt person till dig! Du kan även ringa oss på , maila till kundservice@prendo.se eller skriva till oss direkt i chatten när den är bemannad.[contact-form-7 id="6" title="KONTAKTA OSS"]</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="bestallNu" class="tabcontent">
<ul>
 <li><h3>[icon name="shopping-cart" class="" unprefixed_class=""]  Beställ nu</h3></li>
 <li>Nu är du ett steg närmre! Välj önskad variant och antal och lägg sedan till produkten i varukorgen. Känner du dig osäker och behöver hjälp får du gärna kontakta oss.[contact-form-7 id="6" title="KONTAKTA OSS"]</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You are only setting the `active` class on the button that was clicked, but you need to set it for the “actual” tab button as well. (Resp. figure out how to get to the tab button, not sure the actually clicked button needs it in this case.)

Answer (score 1):

Use classList instead:

To add:

```
evt.currentTarget.classList.add("mystyle");
```

To remove:

```
evt.currentTarget.classList.remove("mystyle");
```

To toggle:

```
evt.currentTarget.classList.toggle("mystyle");
```

To replace:

```
evt.currentTarget.classList.replace( oldClass, newClass );
```

More info can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList).